# C Program not working

Tags: c

I'm writing a code which shows the largest of entered numbers, but when run it returns a seemingly random number, my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int largest;
    int nvalue;
    int no1, no2, no3;

    printf("Enter value of n:");
    scanf("%d\n", &nvalue);

    printf ("Number1:");
    scanf("%d\n", &no1);

    printf("Number2:");
    scanf("%d\n", &no2);

    printf("Number3:");
    scanf("%d\n", &no3);

    largest == nvalue;
    if (no1 > nvalue) {
        printf ("The largest number is:%d\n", &no1); }
    else if (no2 > nvalue) {
        printf("The largest number is %d\n", &no2); }
    else if (no3 > nvalue) {
        printf("The largest number is %d\n", &no3); }
    else {
        printf("The largest number is %d\n", &largest); }

    return 0;
}
```

when run it returns:

```
Enter value of n:3
3
Number1:34
Number2:89
Number3:54
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks
The largest number is -1536115152

Comment: The %d format in printf isn't expecting a pointer to an integer, it's expecting an integer. So your printf's are actually printing a pointer value as an integer.

Comment: Learn from this link http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/largest-number-three

Comment: It returns as before but the 'largest number' is now -831125744

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, your logic is entirely wrong. You should not initialize `largest` to *the number of entries* – they are not related! In addition, you are only comparing one at a time.

Comment: Remove \n from scanf and add it in printf statements...

Comment: Sorry I was responding to the previous comment, thats fantastic thank you.

Comment: I think you should read some C tutorials. There are lot of mistakes in your code, for example what does this `largest == nvalue` do? Also what is the purpose of both variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you writing this line `largest = nvalue;` ?
And your if-else if commands are totally wrong.
Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int largest = 0;
    int no1, no2, no3;

    printf("Number1: ");
    scanf("%d", &no1);

    printf("Number2: ");
    scanf("%d", &no2);

    printf("Number3: ");
    scanf("%d", &no3);

    if ((no1 > no2) && (no1>no3)){
        largest=no1; 
    }
    else if ((no2 > no1) && (no2>no3)) {
        largest=no2; 
    }
    else {
        largest=no3; 
    }
    printf("The largest number is:%d", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome but I think you should learn C programming with a little more effort because there were a lot of errors in your code.

Comment: I'm still very new at the language, doing it at university but my lecturer isn't very helpful so trying to learn it myself to my best effort.

Comment: Which answer did you mark correct? Mine or user3302647 ??? Which one is working ??? @A.Rae

Comment: Yours, apologies I'm still new to this website.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `&` in `printf`, it returns address of that variable.

Comment: With this its some progress, but returning 34 rather than 89 which is the largest

Comment: Your conditions are wrong. Try to implement the following logic. store first variable in a temporary variable, cimpare it with second. If temp is lesser than second number then update temp with second and do the same for third an fourth number. REMEMBER: for learning purposes the best way is to make your on logic.

Comment: The above logic can be implemented for any number of variables. Try it yourself..  best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Code should be well formatted e.g code inside curly braces ({ }) should be indented properly (this makes it easier to read your code).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

Variables should be descriptive (helpful if other people are reading over your code).

```
    int largest = 0;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;
```

The newline character ('\n) isn't necessary, unless you want scanf to take the newline character as part of your input.

```
    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("Enter the third number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num3);
```

This is a much cleaner and simpler check to see which is the largest number. (taken from [Rishav Choudhuri's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36664988/6179830) code above)

```
    if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
    {
        largest = num1;
    }
    else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3)
    {
        largest = num2;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = num3;
    }

    printf("The largest number is : %d", largest);

    return 0;
}
```

I also recommend reading this book [The C Programming Language 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) and reading some tutorials online

also be sure to write lots of code as well :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) {
    int largest = INT_MIN;
    int n, value;
    int i;

    printf("Enter value of n:");//fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        printf ("Number%d:", i);//fflush(stdout);
        if(1 != scanf("%d", &value)){
            printf("invalid input!\n");
            while(getchar() != '\n');//clear input
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        if(value > largest)
            largest = value;
    }
    printf("The largest number is %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}
```